# session attribute not getting updated in WebLogic 12c

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, java-ee-7

I just updated my application to WebLogic 12c, and have discovered that calling session.setAttribute() on an existing attribute is not updating it.

For example, let's say I have an object called myData with a String firstName == "John."  Then I first set myData in MY_DATA_ATTR attribute as follows:

```
request.getSession(false).setAttribute(MY_DATA_ATTR, myData);
```

When I later call request.getSession(false).getAttribute(MY_DATA_ATTR), it gets the data I expect.  But then if the user makes a change so that firstName == "Joe", and my code in turn calls again

```
request.getSession(false).setAttribute(MY_DATA_ATTR, myData);
```

The session object still has the firstName == "John" instead of "Joe".

I switched back and forth between WebLogic 11g and 12c with the exact same code, and in the 11g env, the session object changed as expected.  Is there something I can do to fix it in the weblogic config?  Otherwise the only thing I can think of is to change the code, which is not something I want to deal with.

Comment: Can you check you are always working on the same session between your calls to setAttribute(). Just dispay the session id to do it (request.getSession(false).getId()

Comment: Yes, I checked and the session Ids are identical

Comment: Can you share the code used for the test ?